# unable to get user's response in assisstant on firebase cloud function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I need one help, I am not getting the user's response in the dialogflow firebase functions. please find the coding in index.js
      Here in the TestIntent, i want to get user's response(user answer), i tried with "app.intent('Test Intent',(conv,input)" , and used "${input}" in "ask". Now i tried with "app.intent('Test Intent',(conv,params)", i am not getting user's response. Please let me know, how to get the user's response"

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as gApp from 'actions-on-google';
import { myService } from './services/myService';
const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const {Card, Suggestion} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
import admin from 'firebase-admin';
const app = gApp.dialogflow({debug: true});

process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:debug'; 

//exports.dialogflowSample = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => 
//{


  app.intent('Default Welcome Intent',(conv) => {
    conv.ask(`Welcome to my dialogFlow agent! <say-as >${input}</say-as>.</speak>`);
    //conv.data.question = 'question1';

  });


app.intent('Test Intent',(conv,params) => {
    let qNo:string  =   conv.data.question;
    conv.ask('<speak>Testing the application'
    +`<say-as >`+conv.params.pain+`</say-as>.</speak>`);
    conv.ask('<speak>Testing the application'+`<say-as >`+qNo+`</say-as>.</speak>`);
    });

  exports.dialogflowSample = functions.https.onRequest(app);
//});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to return exactly what the user said, you can do that:

```
app.intent('Test Intent',conv => {
    let userRawInput  =   conv.input.raw;
    conv.ask("You said exactly: "+userRawInput);
    });
```

Comment: if i test using google home , Will i get same value in "conv.input.raw" ? ,,

Comment: Did you have guide to refer all the object references in conv, actions-on-google..etc..

Comment: What I did was print the conv object and check its field, then I found what I was interested in and used it